# How to insert data in a specific column only using access and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have 3 columns in `msaccess`. The `NAME | AGE | STATUS`. The `name` and `age` has a data in database and the Status columns are blank. How can I insert a data into Status column only, using vb.net and textbox.

Comment: It's not an insert. Inserting means adding a new record. If you want to modify an existing record then that's an update. You need to do some research and learn the basics of data access, which includes insert, update, delete and select operations.

Comment: Show what you've tried and we'll help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST**

You need to set up your connection.

*e.g.*

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class SQLTools
     Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
     Private Const SqlString As String = "Server= ;Database= ;User ID= ;Password= ;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
     Private myConn As SqlConnection
     Private myCmd As SqlCommand
     Private myReader As SqlDataReader
     Private Sub Conn()
         myConn = New SqlConnection(SqlString)
     End Sub
```

**SECOND**

Now you can code your update query

```
Sub UpdateQuery(ByVal PK As Long, ByVal Val as String)        
    Dim Sql As String= "update TABLE_NAME set Status = @Val Where TABLE_PK = @PK"
    myCmd = New SqlCommand(Sql, myConn)
    myCmd.Parameters.Add("@PK", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK
    myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Val", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Val
    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Update done!")
    myConn.Close()
End Sub
```

**FINAL**

Now you have to call you Sub passing your Textbox value ByVal.

*e.g.*

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    UpdateQuery(tablePk, TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```